# af:inputText align cursor to the left ADF Jdeveloper

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, jspx

I have an inputText which I want the cursor to be aligned to the left and not to the right as in the image

[I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHAgk.png)

and I want this :

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4Pqu.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we have the images posted here instead of going to another tabs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve the issue adding this property **contentStyle="text-align:left;"** to the **af:inputText**, if you are using Jdeveloper 12c in the property panel you can see something like this

[image: Property Panel]

Greetings